# Using bxslider and nivoslider together - bxslider not working and nivoslider working perfect

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider, bxslider

I am trying to use bxslider and nivoSlider together in 1 page.

**But bxslider is not Working at all in my wordpress :(**  Nivo Slider is Working Perfect with no issue.

Here is my nivoslider, that i am using in "header_ins.php" which is getting included in "header.php" file :-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-bar">
                    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/slider/images/header1.jpg" data-thumb="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/slider/images/header1.jpg" alt="" />
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/slider/images/header2.jpg" data-thumb="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/slider/images/header2.jpg" alt="" />
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/slider/images/header3.jpg" data-thumb="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/slider/images/header3.jpg" alt="" />
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/slider/images/header4.jpg" data-thumb="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/slider/images/header4.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/slider/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        });
        </script>
```

And here is my bxslider source code, which i am using in "header.php" file :-

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="js/jquery.Slider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#scroll1').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    displaySlideQty: 3,
    moveSlideQty: 3,
    pager: true
});
});</script>

<div id="slider1">
        <div >
            <a href="#"><img src="2.jpg" />
                <p>test1</p></a>
        </div>         
        <div >
            <a href="#"><img src="2.jpg" />
                <p>test2</p></a>
        </div>         
        <div >
            <a href="#"><img src="2.jpg" />
                <p>test3</p></a>
        </div>         
        <div>
            <a href="#"><img src="2.jpg" />
                <p>test4</p></a>
        </div></div>
```

**But bxslider is not Working at all in my wordpress**  Nivo Slider is Working Perfect with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

That code has a lot of issues:

you're calling jquery twice, since jquery is already part of wordpress, you don't need to add it in the header.php

Hook up the btx script in your functions.php file, then you can call it as you need it.